# How is possession indicated with an apostrophe for a name ending ss?

Tags: apostrophe

Hi assuming you have a name like Cross, Tess or Ross. What is the correct way of writing including the apostrophe assuming the owner is a singular entity?

Eg.

Ross's apples
Ross'es apples

Comment: You would never use "Ross'es". The apostrophe/apostrophe s shows possession, the es (in some cases) shows plural. There is no instance when 'es is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow Strunk & White, so this is Andreas Blass's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You only use *s'* when the noun you are making possessive is plural. It's not enough for the noun to simply end in *s*, or even in *ss*: in those cases, you need an apostrophe followed by another *s*. So:

> Mr. Jones's house
>
> the Joneses' house
>
> Mr. Ross's apples
>
> the Rosses' apples

Comment: To whom does the Jones' car belong?  I have noticed that individual families with last names ending in -ss, -s, or -es develop their own usage patterns which I believe we should adopt on an individual basis.

Comment: I have downmarked this because I believe you are too dogmatic. There is in practice considerable latitude allowed. As for the ones you mention, I would not expect to be criticised for writing them as follows: 'Mr Jones' house'; the Joneses' house; Mr Ross' apples; the Rosses' apples.

Comment: @WS2 I would have thought that meant the belonging to the family with the name jones. The second example not correct and the last example meaning the apples belonging to a group of people named Ross (or Rosses)

Comment: @WS2 That would be wrong. When you talk about the apples of Mr Ross, you add a syllable: hence it **must** be Mr Ross’s apples.  And apostrophe is not sounded, and does not stand in for your "iz" sound. You actually have to write it.

Comment: @tchrist. That is just not true. There are many guides that advocate omitting the s after the apostrophe when a word ends in s. And that doesn't affect the pronunciation. It may even be a BrE vs AmE kind of thing.

Comment: @nxx Just because a lot of people screw it up doesn't make it right. \

Comment: What do you mean they screw it up? 's is no more or less "iz" than s' is.

Comment: You yourself have said in the previous question that is linked "there has never been a time in the history of the English language when all writers [...] agreed upon, any such rule."

Comment: None of this changes my view about Mr Jones' apples, but on reflection I am also disinclined to write 'the Joneses'. What happens when the surname is Matthews? Do you write about 'the Matthewses'? I think not. Where a family name end in an s like that I think my way would be to speak and write of ' the Matthews family', 'the Jones family' and 'the Ross family'. In that case it becomes 'the house of the Jones family'.

Comment: @WS2 But when you and I were young, "keeping up with the Joneses" was a widely-used phrase, cisatlantically, and [**nearly as popular**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keeping+up+with+the+Joneses%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ckeeping+up+with+the+Joneses%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeeping%20up%20with%20the%20Joneses%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeeping%20up%20with%20the%20Joneses%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) on your side

Comment: @StoneyB If I were using that expression I would definitely say and write 'the Joneses'. But my problem is that I would be unlikely to say 'They are trying to keep up with the Matthewses'. I would have to say '...with the Matthews', or 'with the Matthews family' or something, even if their surname ended in an s.

Comment: @StoneyB Further, I would probably speak of the 'Joneses' house. But what if the name is Socrates? Would we speak of 'the Socrateses' house? You might but I am not sure if I would!

Comment: @WS2 To tell the truth, I probably wouldn't add *-es* to *Mathews* in speech or writing. But in the US at least, *Ortiz* is regularly pluralized *Ortizes*; and [here](http://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/2961810/Hankins_ManettiSocrates.pdf?sequence=5)'s a plural Socrates. Perhaps we add *-es* only to final stressed syllables?